# I want to set up a new standalone app to be a part of an existing React app, is Git Submodules a way to achieve this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, git-submodules

I am tasked with building a new section in an old web app. The app is built with an old version of React (0.14.9). [edit: It is also deployed as a mobile app using Cordova] Rather than having to try and update, change, or work within the original app too much, I'd like to be build a separate app with Preact and have it as submodule of the original app.

Ideally, I could then link to this new app through the React-router in the original app, so it could be accessed at "originalapp.com/new" I would also like to gradually migrate and update code from the old app into this new repository.

So far I have set up the new repo as a submodule of the original repo, but I cannot integrate it into the router. I'm not sure how to use the react-router for anything other than react components, or fully external link.

If I want to build this as a new app, is using git submodules a viable approach? Or should I look for another solution?

Comment: what about redirect to the new web app from the old web app? if you do it smartly, there is no need to create any git sub-module.

Comment: The web app is deployed as a mobile app using Cordova (I should have mentioned that in the original post). I don't know if that totally prohibits us from having two separate web apps, but I originally thought that combining them (through git submodules or whatever else) would be more straightforward, when it came to mobile deployment.

Comment: The question I get is "how can you use two versions of react" - and do you want to have two versions of react _on the same page_ or can they be clearly delineated by url?